# Why can we assume the contact time interval is $2L/v_x$ when a single molecule collides with a wall?

Tags: kinetic-theory

In my understanding of Newton's second law
$$F=\frac{\Delta p}{\Delta t}$$
$\Delta t$ is the contact time interval between two objects.

I am reviewing the process to derive $p=\frac{1}{3}\rho v^2_\text{rms}$. There is one step that looks weird to me. The author used $2L/v_x$ as $\Delta t$ to find force acting on the wall when a single molecule elastically collides with the wall.
\begin{align}
F &=\frac{\Delta p}{\Delta t}\\
&= \frac{2mv_x}{\frac{2L}{v_x}}\\
&= \cdots
\end{align}

### Question

Why can we assume the contact time interval between the single molecule of gas and the wall is $2L/v_x$?

### Edit

For a reference, see [Kinetic theory of gases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_theory_of_gases) or for the sake of your convenience, let me attach the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: See [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/607431/why-we-take-time-between-consecutive-collisions-on-the-same-wall-in-derivation-o) answer.

Comment: @josephh: Thank you for the link.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider what happens when a single molecule hits a wall twice, in succession. After it bounces off the wall the first time, it travels the length of the box until it hits the other wall, after which it travels the length of the box again to arrive back to the wall of interest.

This means that the molecule travels a horizontal distance $2L$, with (horizontal) speed $v_x$, so the time interval is $\Delta t=\frac{2L}{v_x}$.

Comment: But $\Delta t$ in Newton's second law is the time interval two objects (molecule and wall) in contact rather than time interval between two consecutive collisions.

Comment: @MoneyOrientedProgrammer Ah, here, the expression means that a gas molecule will deposit $\Delta p$ momentum every $\Delta t$ interval. You should treat these as impulses.

Comment: So, in this way, the time-averaged force is $\Delta p/\Delta t$.

Comment: Sorry. I still don't get the idea.